# xlib.h not found after installing libx11-dev

Tags: linux, x11

I installed libx11-dev package for X11 to get Xlib.h but still my code is giving an error. How can I solve the problem here? I am using Open-suse.

Comment: You need to fix an error. Seriously, how do you think anyone is going to solve your problem without knowing what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the error here is the code is not able to find Xlib.h

Comment: How do you compile your program? Show us your code. How do you include `Xlib.h`?

Comment: It goes like this. I cannot add full code due to characters length limitations. 
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include "mppoint2.h"


namespace MATPACK {

class MpCursorImpl; 
class MpCursor 
{
  private:
    static MpCursorImpl *pimpl;
    int shape;
  public:
    enum
    { 
      Default = 0,
      CrossHair,
      Wait,
      SlideVertical,
      SlideHorizontal,
      TopLeftCorner,
      BottomRightCorner,
      Text,
      HandOpen, 
      HandClosed,
      HandPoint
    };

Comment: Is there `/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h`?

Comment: yes it is there, I added the correct path

Answer (score 1):

The path was incorrect, it was /usr/inlclude/X11/Xlib.h

Comment: Wait a minute, what compiler do you use? Most compilers should look for headers in `/usr/include` by default. There is no need to do `#include </usr/include/X11/Xlib.h>`.